# Range of testing accuracy is large in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have trained my dataset's accuracy above 0.8.

But testing data's accuracy sometimes can be 0.7, and sometimes just 0.2.

(My training dataset and testing dataset are the same.)

What's wrong with my CNN model? 
Thank you.

This is my training model.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(64,64,3))
conv_layer1 = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same')(inputs)
LR1 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(conv_layer1)
conv_layer2 = Conv2D(32,(3,3),padding='same')(LR1)
LR2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(conv_layer2)
max_layer1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(LR2)
conv_layer3 = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(max_layer1)
LR3 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(conv_layer3)
conv_layer4 = Conv2D(64,(3,3),padding='same')(LR3)
LR4 = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(conv_layer4)
max_layer2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(LR4)
conv_layer5 = Conv2D(128,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu')(max_layer2)
max_layer3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_layer5)
conv_layer6 = Conv2D(256,(3,3),padding='same',activation='relu')(max_layer3)
max_layer4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_layer6)
flatten = Flatten()(max_layer4)
dence2 = Dense(64,activation='relu')(flatten)

f1 = Dense(11, activation='softmax', name='prediction_one')(dence2)
f2 = Dense(11, activation='softmax', name='prediction_two')(dence2)
f3 = Dense(11, activation='softmax', name='prediction_third')(dence2)
model2 = Model(outputs=[f1,f2,f3], inputs=inputs)
model2.summary()

model2.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'],optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model2.fit(X_train,[co1_train,co2_train,co3_train],64,epochs=10,validation_data=(X_valid,[co1_valid,co2_valid,co3_valid]))
```

Comment: The model is overfitting on your training dataset, hence it is not generalized for testing dataset. You may need to use the methodologies mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit) to overcome the overfitting problem.